# Can I just split the guitar signal before the amplifier to record it?

Tags: electric-guitar, guitar-effects, effects-pedal, homerecording

My setup is:

```
guitar
-> effects pedal (ME-70)
-> looper pedal (RC-3)
-> amplifier (studio pro 112)
```

I'd like to get the output from the looper pedal into Ableton, while still hearing everything through the amplifier. It seems natural to try to put a 1/4" mono splitter after the looper pedal, with one branch leading to the amplifier and the other leading to my computer through a 1/4"-to-MIDI cable (I have a Rocksmith cable). But since I'm not sure how things can break, I wanted to ask first if this would work? Is there a better approach?

Also, would the same solution work for recording my bass guitar and bass amplifier, or would I have to change something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably just use the Effects Send out from the amp into your computer using your Rocksmith cable directly (I'm assuming you mean 1/4" to USB cable).

A splitter usually isn't ideal for recording, although you probably wouldn't notice any problems going into a USB converter. A better option would be something like a mini-mixer which can isolate the signal and let you send where you want.

Comment: I'll admit the effects pedal is new for me and I didn't realise there was such an output, thank you! That solves a lot of cases. I'm also interested in recording after the looper pedal (I'm not using the multieffects for looping), maybe I'll look into a mixer for that.

Comment: The Effects Send is an output jack on the back of the Amp. It takes the signal you are sending into the amp and sends it out before it goes to the main amp part and the speaker. The RC-3 has dual outputs which could also work as long as you aren't doing stereo effects with it.